# Joomla module building

Tags: php, joomla, module, slider

Alright I hope I'm not copying anyone else in this, but I can't seem to get a straight answer from anywhere.

Working with Joomla 3.0 and trying to create a module which displays a jQuery image slider. I know how to make the slider work static and also how to draw elements from the database upon loading (standard PHP), but I cannot figure out how to add the controls for the back end so that someone else with permissions could change images and links and what have you.

An explanation of what goes where and why, would be awesome.

Also if anyone knows what Joomla command line adds the media manager menu pop up, so that they don't have to know the image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is used in the XML file which will pop up the media manager:

```
<field name="myimage" type="media" directory="stories" />
```

To call the field, use the following:

```
$params->get('myimage');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok so basically anything with a field tag in the XML file is added as an option within the module menu?

Comment: yes correct. this field/value is stored automatically in the database. `$params` is automatically defined so you don't need to do it yourself ;)